# HTML Form Validation using JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, flask

I am trying to develop a web application, and I'm stuck on the register page. Basically I want the user to enter their name, and if the name is blank or does not consist of alphabets, then I want to display a line of error message under the box. I've tried changing the position of the script tag, adding an eventListener, as well as using an internal JavaScript code, but nothing seems to work. This is only a basic code that I've written for testing so please don't mind the plain text. On submitting invalid value, the page just reloads back to the /register page instead of displaying an error.

This is the code for register.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Using the meta tag so that the application looks same on different devices-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title> Readable </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Sign Up for Free</h1>
          <form action="/register" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name"><input type = "text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </label>
                <p id="name_error"></p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" onclick="errorMessage()"> Sign Up </button>
                <script src="script.js"></script>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This my JavaScript code:

```
function errorMessage() {
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const namelen = name.length;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z] + [A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (namelen<1) {
        document.getElementById("name_error").innerHTML = "Name cannot be blank";
        return false;
    } else if(!letters.test(name)) {
        document.getElementById("name_error").innerHTML = "Please enter your full name (first name + last name)";
        return false;
    } else
}
```

And this is my small app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session


#Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

#App route for register page
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")
```

The webpage is correctly displayed and the site works, but no error message :(

Comment: `errorMessage` might `return false`, but your `onclick` function ignores the return value. (You shouldn't use onclick attributes anyway, they have all sorts of gotchas. Now that Internet Explorer 9 has pretty much eliminated Internet Explorer 8 from the marketplace we can use `addEventListener` without any worries).

Comment: `app.py` doesn't appear to have any way to respond to the request for `script.js` with anything but a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: `} else
}` well that is weird code to me as is having the script tag inside a fieldset

Comment: You could correct it with `onclick="return errorMessage()"` but it makes sense to use a more modern  way of assigning listeners.

Comment: what @Quentin said but all versions of  Internet Explorer are dead now and unsupported by Microsoft (Edge replaces it)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss — That was a humorous way of pointing out *how many years* out of date using `onclick` is. I don't expect anybody to think that any version of IE is remotely relevant in all but some very rare edge cases today.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `required` attribute on the `<input>` to demonstrate the empty value error message.

You should utilize true `<form>` submission logic:

```js
function submitForm(event, /* form */) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const
    form = event.target, // The `target` is the `<form>`
    nameInput = form.elements.name,
    nameError = nameInput.closest('fieldset').querySelector('p'),
    nameValue = nameInput.value.trim();
  let errorMessage;
  if (nameValue.length === 0) {
    errorMessage = 'Name cannot be blank';
  } else if (!/^[a-z]+ [a-z]+$/i.test(nameValue)) {
    errorMessage = 'Please enter your full name e.g. "<FirstName> <LastName>"';
  }
  nameError.textContent = errorMessage;
  if (!errorMessage) {
    console.log('Submitting form!');
    //form.submit(); /* Uncomment this line to submit */
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset .error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
<form action="/register" method="post" onsubmit="submitForm(event, this)">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name-input">
      Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name-input" placeholder="John Doe" />
    </label>
    <p class="error"></p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could intercept the submission using an event handler:

```js
document.forms['sign-up'].addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

function submitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const
    form = event.target, // The `target` is the `<form>`
    nameInput = form.elements.name,
    nameError = nameInput.closest('fieldset').querySelector('p'),
    nameValue = nameInput.value.trim();
  let errorMessage;
  if (nameValue.length === 0) {
    errorMessage = 'Name cannot be blank';
  } else if (!/^[a-z]+ [a-z]+$/i.test(nameValue)) {
    errorMessage = 'Please enter your full name e.g. "<FirstName> <LastName>"';
  }
  nameError.textContent = errorMessage;
  if (!errorMessage) {
    console.log('Submitting form!');
    //form.submit(); /* Uncomment this line to submit */
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset .error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
<form name="sign-up" action="/register" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name-input">
      Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name-input" placeholder="John Doe" />
    </label>
    <p class="error"></p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Perhaps wire up the `onsubmit="submitForm(event, this)"` as an event listener instead. But might just be me not liking "code" in the HTML markup

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I added your suggestion at the bottom.